# kafka-streams: joining historical data with a stream

Tags: java, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams

Given that I have the three following topics:

- **topic-a**: events are produced continuously - topic is partitioned but not compacted - updates for previous messages are common
- **topic-b**: events occur on a monthly basis - topic is partitioned but not compacted - events are related to events in topic a - all keys from topic a will be referenced in this topic
- **topic-c**: output topic for events generated by merging a and b

**Objective**: Messages from topic-b need to be enriched with the events stored in topic-a and then published on topic-c.

**Problem**: I cannot join the topics directly, as topic-a contains many duplicates and I need to have exactly a 1:1 match between topic-a and topic-b.

**Idea 1**

- Create a `KTable` *aTable* from topic-a - aggregate events

```
KStream<String, DomainObjectA> aStream = kStreamBuilder.stream(
                aTopic,
                Consumed.with(Serdes.String(), aSerde));
KTable<String, DomainObjectA> aTable = aStream
               .groupByKey()
               .reduce(
                       (value1, value2) -> value2
               );
```

- Join events from topic-b with `KTable` based on stream a (aTable)

```
KStream<String, DomainObjectB> bStream = kStreamBuilder.stream(topicB);
KStream<String, DomainObjectC> cStream = bStream.leftJoin(aTable, getJoiner())
```

**Problem**: this might work, yet AFAIK, the state-store and the underlying topic created by `KTable` *aTable* will grow indefinitely.

**Idea 2**:

- Use windowing:

```
KStream<String, DomainObjectA> aStream = kStreamBuilder.stream(
                aTopic,
                Consumed.with(Serdes.String(), aSerde));
KTable<Windowed<String>, DomainObjectA> aTable = aStream
                .groupByKey()
                .windowedBy(TimeWindows.of(Duration.ofDays(30L)))
                .reduce(
                        (value1, value2) -> value2,
                        Materialized.<String, DomainObjectA, WindowStore<Bytes, byte[]>>as("a-storage").withRetention(Duration.ofDays(30L)));
```

**Problem**: If I understand correctly, this approach should ensure that the underlying topic for the `KTable` and the state-store are bounded and entries will be cleaned up.
However, I end up with a `KTable<Windowed<String>, DomainObjectA>` which I cannot join with my stream:

```
KStream<String, DomainObjectB> bStream = kStreamBuilder.stream(topicB);
KStream<String, DomainObjectC> cStream = bStream.leftJoin(aTable, getJoiner()); // not possible
```

I was able to join by turning stream-b into a windowed `KTable` as well - but I am not sure I like this approach as it will create yet another (this time unnecessary) topic.

**Idea 3**:

Doing things manually by:

- Creating a new compacted topic (topic-d) with 30 day retention-period
- Create a new topology which pushes all messages from topic-a to topic-d
- Join all values from topic-b with topic-d - directly joining the steams without any `KTable`s
  While having some overhead, I think this might work, however it feels like I am by-passing the framework somehow.

So in the end my question is: what is the best way to achieve a join of historical data with a stream using kafka-streams? While idea 2 might work I think idea 3 is the
better approach as it requires only one additional topic and no state-stores.